# Sliding window using deque (runtime error)

Tags: c++, data-structures, runtime-error, deque

In the following program, I am trying to find the maximum in window size of `k` in an array of length `n`. For reference, the question is from [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/sliding-window-maximum/).

For example, if the array is [2 5 3 1 2] and window size is 3, then I have windows as [2 5 3], [5 3 1], [3 1 2] and corresponding maximums are 5, 5, 3.

I am using `std::deque` for this purpose but it is giving runtime error, I don't think any **pointer invalidations** are happening, I cannot find any. Please help me, I am stuck for a long time on this.

Here's my code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> maxSlidingWindow(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
        deque<int> d;
        for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
            while (!d.empty() && d.front() < nums[i]) {
                d.pop_front();
            }
            d.push_front(nums[i]);
        }
        vector<int> ans;
        ans.push_back(d.back());

        int n = nums.size();
        for (int i = k; i < n; ++i) {
            while (1) {
                int elem = d.back();
                d.pop_back();
                if (elem == nums[i-k]) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            while (!d.empty() && d.front() < nums[i]) {
                d.pop_front();
            }
            d.push_front(nums[i]);
            ans.push_back(d.back());
        }
        return ans;
    }
};
```

Error message shown is this:

```
Line 157: Char 16: runtime error: reference binding to misaligned address 0xbebebebebebec0ba for type 'int', which requires 4 byte alignment (stl_deque.h)
0xbebebebebebec0ba: note: pointer points here
<memory cannot be printed>
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/bits/stl_deque.h:162:16
```

Comment: Please prove that the error is not outside of the code you are showing, by providing a [mre].

Comment: @Yunnosch Actually the website didn't provide its internal code and only displays the class which user can edit. But after some time I figured out that clicking on playground, I can get access to internal functions. So here is the complete code given in question: https://pastebin.com/p0Fk3z2V
In this, the vector is provided as enclosed in brackets in stdin, like [2, 5, 3, 1, 2], and k is provided in next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe this part of your code:

```
while (1) {
    int elem = d.back();         // get element
    d.pop_back();                // pop element

    if (elem == nums[i-k]) {     // compare element
        break;                   // and break on success
    }                            // What happens on failure???
}                                // Inifinite loop and UB!
```

The `while` loop is not exiting.

With its every iteration, you're accessing and popping an element from deque until it is empty because `elem` is not equal to `nums[i-k]`.

Change `while (1)` to:

```
while ( !d.empty() )
```

Because you can get and pop an element from the deque only when it's not empty!

And, calling `back()` and `pop_back()` on an empty deque is [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub):

From the documentation of [std::deque::back()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/back):

> Calling `back` on an empty container causes undefined behavior.

Same goes for [std::deque::pop_back()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/pop_back):

> Calling `pop_back` on an empty container is undefined.

Comment: Yes this was the issue, apart from that the algorithm is also not working correctly. Thanks for answer!

Comment: Thankfully I figured out how to correct it, here is corrected code. Basically the element which was at i-k was getting removed from deque. Then only time we needed to remove it was when deque.back() had that element: https://pastebin.com/NgRrqWfM

Comment: @jeea: That's great! Glad it helped and you finally made it to work. Keep going! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I couldn't resist to make an alternative implementation.

Thereby, I tried to resemble closer the metapher of the sliding window – i.e. to slide a start and end index over the existing vector to determine the maxima for the sub-ranges.

I still had in mind that there exists a [std::max()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) flavor which accepts an initializer list. (It was my original intention to use it somehow.)

However, while I was googling (to recall the details and have the links at hand) I stumbled into something even better (provided by [<algorithm>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) as well):

[**std::max_element**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element)

> Finds the greatest element in the range [first, last).

So, I made an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see how it could look like with `std::max_element()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> maxSlidingWindow(
  const std::vector<int> &nums, // the sample data
  int k) // the length of sliding window
{
  if (k <= 0) return { }; // no maxima for insufficient range
  if ((size_t)k > nums.size()) k = nums.size(); // Ehem... window too large
  std::vector<int> ans;
  //ans.reserve(num.size() - k); // allocate final size at once (for more speed)
  for (size_t i = k; i <= nums.size(); ++i) {
    ans.push_back(
      *std::max_element(nums.begin() + i - k, nums.begin() + i));
  }
  return ans;
}      

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const std::vector<int> &vec)
{
  const char *sep = "";
  for (int value : vec) {
    out << sep << value;
    sep = " ";
  }
  return out;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> sample = { 2, 5, 3, 1, 2 };
  std::cout << "Input: " << sample << '\n';
  std::cout << "Output: " << maxSlidingWindow(sample, 3) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
Input: 2 5 3 1 2
Output: 5 5 3
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de0f74bf6626be70)

Comment: Thank you for answer! but there is a problem with this approach, it is calculating in O(n*k) where n, k can be 1e5. So we need a O(n) solution, after debugging and Azem's answer I came to this : https://pastebin.com/NgRrqWfM